# Are draw calls sequenced in command buffers?

Tags: vulkan

Suppose I have two `VkPipelines` and within a `VkCommandBuffer` I record...

```
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmd, /*...*/);
vkCmdBindPipeline(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline1);
vkCmdDraw(cmd, /*...*/); // [1]
vkCmdBindPipeline(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline2);
vkCmdDraw(cmd, /*...*/); // [2]
vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmd);
```

When the command buffer is queued and executed, will it be as-if the rendering operations to the framebuffer attachments of [1] are fully realized before [2] starts executing.

ie Will [2] draw over [1] ?

Comment: Note that the term "side effect" has a *very specific meaning* in Vulkan. In particular, side effects *cannot* happen to attachments, as this would require that the image being used as an attachment be assigned to a descriptor within the pipeline. Which is expressly forbidden (outside of input attachments, to which you cannot cause side effects). So... what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @NicolBolas: That specific meaning was not intended.  Suppose [1] colors the entire framebuffer red and [2] colors the entire framebuffer blue - is the framebuffer gauranteed to be blue after this command buffer executes?

Comment: _Suppose [1] colors the entire framebuffer red_ `vkCmdDraw` doesn't color a framebuffer, you clear an attachment with other commands. But if you mean [1] draws a primitive and [2] draws another primitive on top of the first, then yes - there's a guarantee that you'll see only the second primitive (**24.2. Rasterization Order**).

Comment: @nikitablack: Yes, that is what I mean.  The vertex shader draws a quad that covers the entire framebuffer and every fragment is colored red or blue respectively by the fragment shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most stages in Vulkan execute in an arbitrary order relative to each other. However, [rasterization order](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/chap24.html#primrast-order) is respected with regard to framebuffer attachment processes within a subpass (between subpasses, you have to use subpass dependencies, and outside of the renderpass, you'll need either external subpass dependencies or a barrier). Each primitive is ordered relative to each other primitive, and the implementation must respect rasterization order when doing reordering.

The stages that follow rasterization order atomically include depth/stencil test, blending, write masking, and the like, but they *do not* include the fragment shader itself. That is, FS outputs have to go through rasterization order, but FS *side effects* (ie: writes via image store or SSBOs) do not.

Answer (score 3):

There's a set of rules defined in **24.2. Rasterization Order** regarding primitive drawing in a single subpass. According to these rules, blending operations and color writes of the second primitive should happen strictly after blending operations and color writes of the first primitive.